# Entity Framework, calling a procedure through FromSqlRaw()

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am replacing a very long sql statement in C# with a stored procedure. The sql was called by the FromSqlRaw function. What piece of EF functionality can be implemented to achieve the same result. The following returns an exception error near b6f42 or similar each time I run the program. The procedure results called from SSMS are satisfactory.

```
var wrk = DbCtx.WRK.FromSqlRaw($"Execute GetCustomersAsync 
        {Id} {LastName}").ToObservableCollection();
```

Comment: Can you post the error message  too pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SqlQuery` for that:

```
           var param1 = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Date",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
                Value = validityEnd
            };
            var parameters = new SqlParameter[] { param1 };

            return context
                .Set<TEntity>()
                .SqlQuery<ReturnType>(
                    "[schema].[spName] @Date",
                    parameters);
```

Comment: is SqlQuery a method? EF created my dataconext class and there is no definition for that method.

Comment: Yes, this is DbSet<> method. Updated my answer

Comment: If you are using EF Core then you can have a look on following link https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx